# How to display rectangular div with data on mouse over event of any node in d3 js tree?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a tree using d3 js. Now i on mouse over any node,a rectangular box containing node name and id should be displayed.
I tried this

But this does not work on mouse over any node.How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot append HTML elements (div, p, h1, h2 etc) to a SVG. The tag can even show up when you inspect the DOM, but it simply doesn't work.

This is what you can do:

First, set the CSS style for the tooltip, using a div with a class named "tooltip":

```
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: /*whatever*/;           
    white-space: /*whatever*/;                  
    padding: /*whatever*/;              
    font-size: /*whatever*/;        
    background: /*whatever*/;   
    border: /*whatever*/;   
    border-radius: /*whatever*/;            
    pointer-events: /*whatever*/;
    etc...          
}
```

Then set a tooltip var (here, #svgId is the Id of the element where you append your svg, not much different of selecting "body" as you did):

```
var tooltip = d3.select("#svgId").append("div") 
            .attr("class", "tooltip")               
            .style("opacity", 0);
```

The div has 0 opacity. Then it's just a matter of showing the tooltip on mouseover or mousemove:

```
nodeEnter.on("mousemove", function(d) {
            tooltip.html("<strong> Look, I'm bold !</strong> and now I'm 
                    not bold <br> and this is another line! and this
                    is my data:" + d.whatever)
                    .style('top', d3.event.pageY - 12 + 'px')
                    .style('left', d3.event.pageX + 25 + 'px')
                    .style("opacity", 1);
        });

nodeEnter.on("mouseout", function(d) {
            tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
        });
```

PS: This is a list of SVG elements that you can append (without using `foreignObject`): http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_reference.asp

Comment: I tried what you said but it didn't work......i want to append div to each node and adding your code to mine...it gave an error that tooltip is undefined....Could you please give a fiddle ?

Comment: Once again, you cannot append a div to these nodes. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/0w19eh8q/1/

Comment: You are saying that one cannot append div to svg but in code we are doing this var info = g.append('div').......so can we append div to a g tag?

Comment: No, you can't. You can even write `append("crazytag")`, and it will show up when you inspect the DOM, but it's not valid. You cannot append a div or any other HTML tag to a SVG group. You are doing it wrong. Did you see the Fiddle? It's working without problems.

Comment: I saw the fiddle ,it is working...but i want to understand what are we doing here g.append('div').You appended a div right?

Comment: This is not my code. In my code I don't append any div to any group: I append the div to the body. Check again. It's the `var tooltip`.

Comment: oh so sorry,that was my code in your fiddle that i was confused with...what  is div.tooltip element?what type of element is it?.....................Anyways Thank you so much for helping me out :)

Comment: No worries. `div.tooltip` is a div with a class "tooltip". I used it to style in the CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much.......could you please help me with this?    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370444/highlight-and-un-highlight-path-from-selected-node-to-root-node-in-a-collapsible